# Creating a 'Signed Product' function using basic algebraic/arithmetic functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Lets assume a function $f(x, y) = r$ called the 'signed product function' which behaves as follows.

1. if $x<y$, $r=-(x*y)$
2. else $r=+(x*y)$

Moreover:

1. In any pair $x, y$ at least one value is either $0$ or $1$.
2. For any input value $v$ that is neither $0$ or $1$, $0<v<1$.

I am struggling to construct such a function using basic mathematical operations like: $+, -, *, /, Abs(x), Sqrt(x)$ [where Abs(x) returns the absolute value] but i think it is feasible.

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: $r(x,y) = \frac {x-y}{|x-y|}\cdot x\cdot y$.

Comment: @fleablood What if $x=y$?

Comment: That never happens by condition 2.

Comment: @fleablood How? What if $x=y=1$?

Comment: That also never happens by condition 2

Comment: @fleablood What part of condition $2$ forbids this case.

Comment: Oh... wait.  I misinterpreteed "for any input value of $v$ that is neither $0$ nor $1$" as "for the other value that *isn't* the one considered in condition 1".  Yes.  You are correct and we need a condition for that.....

Comment: I suppose I should ask why?  A function defined but $f(x) = $ one thing if one condition and another if another condition, is every bit as legitimate and valid as a function that uses "basic mathematical operations".  Also absolute value itself, isn't basic as it's defined on a conditional.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need $SIGN\times xy$ where $SIGN = \begin{cases} -1&x< y\\+1&x \ge y\end{cases}$.

A common we you to get such a sign function is divide a value by its absolute value.  In this case an expression that is  negative if and only if $x < y$ divided by its absolute value.  That would be $SIGN = \frac {x-y}{|x-y|}$.

The big issue with this sort of of $SIGN = \frac {expression}{|expression|} = \begin{cases} +1\\-1\end{cases}$ is what to do if $expression = 0$.

An alternative to consider the greatest integer functer $[M]$ to be defined as $[M]$ is the unique integer, $n$ so that $n \le M < n+1$.  The thing about this is that if $-1 < m< 0$ then $[m] =-1$ and if $0 \le m< 1$ then $[m] = 0$.

Now for any $m$ we can "squish" $m$ to a number whose absolute value less than one by noting $-1 < \frac m{|m| + 1} < 1$ and $\frac m{|m|+1}$ will be the same sign as $m$.

So $[\frac m{|m| + 1}] = \begin{cases}0&m \ge 0\\ -1&m< 0\end{cases}$

A little bit of manipulation

$2[\frac m{|m|+1}] -1 =\begin{cases}1&m \ge 0\\ -1&m< 0\end{cases}$

And so

$2[\frac {x-y}{|x-y| + 1}] - 1 = \begin{cases} -1&x-y <0\implies x < y\\+1&otherwise\end{cases}$

And there you go:

> $r(x,y) = (2[\frac {x-y}{|x-y| + 1}] - 1)xy$.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I think the 'greatest integer function' is essentially a conditional function as i don't see a way to implement it using simple algebraic operations (without some logical tests which are similar in nature to our problem itself). Thus we seem to be solving one problem working on the assumption that some other function exists or can be implemented. I am from CS background and we call these 'oracle solutions'. I am afraid it might not be sufficient because of that.

Comment: " But I think the 'greatest integer function' is essentially a conditional function as i don't see a way to implement it using simple algebraic operations"  Same could be said about the absolute value function.

Comment: not necessarily. ACos(Cos(x)) for the range of x we are considering would work as an Abs(x) of if i am correct.

Comment: I have to wonder *why* you are trying to do this.  There is not virtuous or pure about avoiding conditional conditions.  And it's capricious that somehow we must avoid max integer, or max function or $\begin{cases} -(xy)& x<y\\(xy)&x\ge y\end{cases}$ because they are conditional you somehow allow $|x| = \begin{cases} x&x\ge 0\\-x&x < 0\end{cases}$ just because is is convenient.

Comment: But $\arccos$ can't be considered "basic" as *its* definition is "then value of $y$ so that $\cos y = x$".  If anything that is much *more* "oracle" than greatest integer function.

Comment: Please consider any function or expression where we can just feed in the values and get the required result without failure or exceptions and without testing 'if else' or 'human intervention or eyeballing' [like we do in conditionals or all other possibilities] as a valid/simple function. The objective is it to be purely mechanical upto the last bit.

Comment: Anyway..the only problem with $\frac {x-y}{|x-y|}$ is if $x = y$ and we are only dealing with values between $1$.  I think you could figure some triggy thing to avoid zeros in much the way least integers do.  Good "sign functions"

Comment: "Please consider any function or expression where we can just feed in...."  Um... why?  Why should I consider those?  And again.... Absolute value function fails that.  But you can use your cosign modification or some modification to get a sign function.  It's a known problem.  Google "sign functions"

Comment: i am failing in divide by zero and other stuff that is why i posted the Q here.. But it seems the answer seems to be unknown here too.. P.S. my statement regarding the absolute value function was regarding the range of values the variable can take and it works fine for that. I am limiting everything to my problem above. If you disagree with the word 'basic' say 'mechanical' or anything else that pleases or is correct. The objective was to explain the restrictions on types of functions allowed. that's all.